# Imported fbx camera from NUKE is rotated the wrong way

Tags: camera, tracking

I tracked a scene in nuke and created geo for particles to interact with in blender.[image] But when i import the .fbx generated from the write geo node into blender, the camera is rotated the wrong way.[image] The translation of the camera is correct, but the direction it is facing is completley wrong. How can i fig this?

Comment: You can try to export as alembic (ogawa) instead. I can't test it at the moment, however I'm sure there is an fbx import setting that works (perhaps -z y-up)...

Comment: Can anyone test out any of the tracks and see if they work in your blender? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e6sashji7njtd69/AABl79mKcv3etkyMdR61HfJna?dl=0 I imported the pftrack into maya and it works flawlessly. So i tried exporting the track from maya and it still doesn't work in blender...

Comment: I wonder, if it's just a matter of wrong rotation why not use camera delta transforms to compensate, or maybe parent a second camera to that one and make it active

Comment: best way is to use a script after import to scale (100x) and rotate all the cameras 90 degrees on local y axis (individual origins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: Import fbx into maya and export that scene using the DAE_fbx export. And then just import into blender using the .dae import option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do so is to change the camera's delta scale:

**Import FBX** *(from Nuke)*

[image: import fbx]

**Set Camera's Delta Scale and Rotation Mode**

[image: set cameras delta scale]

and [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-export-3d-camera-from-nuke-to-blender/639529/19) you may find my original post in blender artists:

Comment: Welcome to the site! We try to keep all necessary details within the answers so that if a link breaks in the future the answer is still valid. Could you edit your question and add some details to it?

Comment: yes you are right, I think it is better now with more info and details even than the original post. :)